# WebView in a tab blank when go back

Tags: android, android-fragments, webview, tabs

Well, I have a webview in a tab when I am showing a piece of information. The problem is that when I change of fragment (I'm using that) and go back then the webview is blank (black).

I am using `loadDataWithBaseURL` method and I've tried to fill the `historyUrl` param but I get the same results.

Here is a piece of my code:

```
String html ="<html><head>" +
            "<style type=\"text/css\">"+
            "@font-face { font-family: '"+ AppData.getFont(context)+"'; src: url('"+AppData.getFont(context)+"'); }"+
            "* {font-family: '"+AppData.getFont(context)+"'; font-size: "+font+" !important; font-weight:normal !important;}"+
            "h1 {font-size: "+h1+" !important;}"+
            "strong, b {font-family: '"+AppData.getFont(context)+"'; font-weight: bold !important;}"+
            "</style>"+
            "</head><body>",
            ending="</body></html>";

    Log.e("HTML", html);
    String filename = "file:///android_asset/";

    String myHtmlString = html + product.getCurrentDescription(context) + ending;
    tvDescription.loadDataWithBaseURL(filename, myHtmlString, "text/html; charset=utf-8", "utf-8", filename);
```

This is the method that I use to manage the tabs:

```
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    TextView tvTabDescription = (TextView) inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_tab_text,null);
    TextView tvTabCondition = (TextView) inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_tab_text,null);
    TextView tvTabLocation = (TextView) inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_tab_text,null);

    //Creating custom tabs
    tvTabDescription.setText(context.getResources().getString(R.string.tab_description));
    tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setCustomView(tvTabDescription));

    tvTabCondition.setText(context.getResources().getString(R.string.tab_conditions));
    tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setCustomView(tvTabCondition));

    tvTabLocation.setText(context.getResources().getString(R.string.tab_location));
    tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setCustomView(tvTabLocation));

    tabLayout.setTabGravity(TabLayout.GRAVITY_FILL);

    final PagerAdapter pagerAdapter = new com.iurban.iurbanapp.Adapters.PagerAdapter(getFragmentManager(),tabLayout.getTabCount(), product, context);
    viewPager.setAdapter(pagerAdapter);
    viewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new TabLayout.TabLayoutOnPageChangeListener(tabLayout));

    tabLayout.setOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
            viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
            if(tab.getPosition() == 2)
                ivProduct.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            else
                ivProduct.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }

        @Override
        public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

        }
    });
```

I am going to share these two pictures, the first one is at the first arrive at this part and the second one is after click on "Reservar" button and go back.

[image]

[image]

When I click on "Reservar" button, it load the FormFragment Fragment:

```
formFragment = new FormFragment();
    fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.fm_container, formFragment)
            .addToBackStack(CustomConstants.FORM).commit();
```

and the go back executes the onBackPressed() android method that calls super.onBackPressed();

My FormFragment's onCreate looks like the next piece of code, the both method only do "initializing components(getting views from xml)" and "initializing mehtods onClick for this components":

```
 @Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_form, container, false);
    initComponent(rootView);
    initOnClicks();
    return rootView;
}
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Could you post your code of framment which load your web and activity which fragment was attached?

Comment: Of course, i'll edit the post to show the managment method of the tabs

Comment: please add two pictures ,one is normal and another is exception.I'll reproduce your issue and tell you solution.

Comment: Ok, I'll edit the post and upload the pictures, one of them working as the tab is at the beginning and the other one when I tab the back button after go to the next fragment, thank you.

Comment: Add code snippet of Reservar listener,I want to know how you go back,maybe it's logic error of go back.

Comment: sure! I've just to edit it again.

Comment: You set a new fragment so you'll see the default backgroud color of fragment.Could you tell me what you really want to do,maybe there's anthor better way .

Comment: Ok I see, what I want to do is only that when I go back (this is not neccesary but it's a possibility) is that the webview shows the same text. I amusing fragment in the entire app to do this more free-flowing for the users.

Comment: So you need set view for your new fragment,do you know how to set it?

Comment: No, I don't know what you mean.

Comment: What's your FormFragment onCreateView looks like,post its layout file?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understood your problem correctly, but you can save your WebView's state and restore it when user navigates back to it.

Here's the example code snippet. You should put this code snippet into your `Fragment` which you use `WebView`.

```
@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    webView.saveState(outState);
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
}
```

And in your fragment's onCreateView or onViewCreated method restore it like the following:

```
if (savedInstanceState != null){
   webview.restoreState(savedInstanceState);
}
else{
   webview.loadUrl(url)
}
```

Comment: Hi, I think that this could help me, but  where could you put it? and how could you call it? thanks.

Comment: i edited my answer. you find where to put this code snippet.

Comment: Ok, it didn't work to me, I guess beacause I have a fragment with the webview inside a fragment which I replace.

Comment: i think it still should work. can you post your fragment replace code?

Comment: can you try to use childFragmentMaanger? if you're using fragment inside a fragment.